# Why when use custom action bar home button image changed from app logo to app icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-homebutton

in AndroidManifest i set same this

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/picA"
    android:logo="@drawable/picB"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    ...
```

When i use default action bar and set DisplayHomeAsUpEnabled to true and set HomeButtonEnabled to true with this code

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

the action bar home button image is "picB"

But when i use custom action bar and set this

```
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
```

the action bar home button image is "picA" Why? And How to change home button image to picB ?

I want my custom action bar home button image is picB same use default action bar

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I'm very stupid

I'm solve my problem by this

```
ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO
```

it's work well